# Does .Net Core 2.1 Support LINQ and Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have tried the following code on Visual Studio Code with OmniSharp extension has been installed. I installed .Net core 2.1.3.

```
List<MyType> listName = dataTableName.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new MyType()
{
    ID = m.Field<string>("ID"),
    Description = m.Field<string>("Description"),
    Balance = m.Field<double>("Balance"),
}).ToList()
```

But it seem not to be able use AsEnumerable(). And the message "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" was showed. These are my using:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RestfulAPI.Commons;
using RestfulAPI.Models.DBModels;
```

How can I use LinQ on .Net Core? 
LinQ seem to be supported by .Net Framework. But I want my webservices API can run on Linux server. Have risk if use your solution, I cannot run my webservices on Linux server?

Comment: Have you tried removing `.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. And Visual Studio Code show the error message "Cannot convert lambda expression...".

Comment: What is the full error text of "Cannot convert lambda expression..."?

Comment: What is the type of `dataTableName`?

Comment: The type of `dataTableName` is System.Data.DataTable. The error text is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type [RestfulAPI]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable` does not implement an Enumerator in .NET Core 2.1. This issue is open in [Dotnet Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27610), so might be implemented some day.

This means you will need to use a loop to iterate over the rows. You cannot use foreach because DataTable has not implemented `IEnumerable` either.

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dataTable.Rows[i];

    var temp = new MyType(){
        ID = row["ID"],
        Description = row["Description"],
        Balance = Double.Parse(row["Balance"].ToString())
     };

     retList.Add(temp);     
}
```

You can also write your own `AsEnumerable` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRow> AsEnumerable(this DataTable table)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return table.Rows[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you know this info? I mean "DataTable does not implement an Enumerator in .NET Core 2.1.". There is not this info in Microsoft's document.

Comment: @ONLAEG they don't seem to specifically mention it in the documentation, but this issue was discussed on their Github https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19771

Comment: Are LINQ expressions generally supported in .NET Core?

Comment: @Exa yep they are, just not with Datatables.

Comment: Looks like this has been included as part of .NET Core 3.0